# Connecting to a secure gateway from Java in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I'm trying to connect to a web server (http/port:80) via a secure gateway (DataPower) from my Bluemix account. I have set everything up and I can see the destination etc. is enabled in my dashboard. I am using Java to connect to the secure gateway but I must be missing something since I keep getting a 403 returned from the gateway client.

I have added:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

But it still fails with a 403.  I'm assuming that I also need to supply the Gateway Id... but cannot find any docs or Java examples...

Comment: Can you share the url you are trying to hit along with the above request properties?

Comment: Hi,  dpev755.innovate.ibm.com port 80.

Comment: James, this is a bad website to test against.  If you fire up firebug you will notice it gives the same error, "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://dpev755.innovate.ibm.com/", along with a redirected webpage.  I would try something else, like google.  I will share my answer below.